# Are Stack Exchange URL parameters defined anywhere?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, slug

Are the parameters used in Stack Exchange URLs defined anywhere?

For example, I just encountered a stackexchange.com URL with `rq=1`, and I frequently encounter stackexchange.com URL's with `cb=1`.